# Same name headers with different content in Ubuntu system

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, gcc

I have two c++ projects in my Eclipse that uses same function `gettimeofday()`. First project compiles fine while other reports error

```
error: ‘gettimeofday’ was not declared in this scope
```

By presing F3 on function name I found that in first project case I was navigated to `/usr/include/86_64-linux-gnu/sys/time.h`. Second project also has `#include <time.h>`, but F3 navigates to `sys/time.h`, which has no ‘gettimeofday’ function.

Why same `#include <time.h>` navigates to different folders?
Why Linux has two same names includes at all?
Why both includes `#include <time.h>` are different?

UPD

I found that `/sys/timeb.h` has inclusion `#include <time.h>` which navigates to `/usr/lib/time.h`. I was expecting `/sys/timeb.h` will include `/sys/timeb.h. How Eclipse and GCC decides to go`/usr/lib/time.h`or`/sys/time.h` ?

Why "professional" `/sys/timeb.h` leaves ambiguity in code just by making `#include <time.h>` instead defining more exact path? I suppose `<time.h>` might point to both - `<sys/time.h>` and `C` `<time.h>`

Comment: Reading up on where `#include`s are searched will show that there's an order of precedence, so the more relative your specified path is, the more potential there is for ambiguity or even error.

Answer (score 1):

On Linux, the function `int gettimeofday(struct timeval *tv, struct timezone *tz);` is defined in `#include <sys/time.h>`.  When using it in your code you should include it exactly like that.  The other time.h is the standard C library that contains time structures and functions such as `time_t` and `mktime`. When you are using this file in a C++ program you should include it as `#include <ctime>` which should help you avoid this type of error in the future.

Comment: `<ctime>` not contains `gettimeofday()`, but it contains inclusion of `time.h`, that points to `/usr/include/time.h` (that according to your description is `C` library). So, `<ctime>` points into `C` lib instead `C++` ? And where is logic to name files the same name `time.h`?

Comment: Why *not* name them the same? They are in different places so still have completely different include paths, because one is under 'sys' and the other is not. If you just include 'time.h' it will never include the one under 'sys' unless you have added the 'sys' directory to your include paths.

Comment: @vico your problem boils down to include paths.  You want to make sure your include path is reasonable within your development environment.  I gave you the "best practices" answer for how to include these time APIs into your compilation units.  From there, you just need to make sure your build environment can resolve the correct include paths.